# Plot won't display fully

Tags: plotting

This is my code, but it won't display the entire plot.
It used to display fully, so I have no idea what happened. Any ideas?

```
V[x_] := Which[x < 0, 400, x > 4, 400, True, 0]
Plot[V[x], {x, -1, 5}, Axes -> False, FrameLabel -> {x, V},
Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {-10, 500}, PlotPoints -> 150]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: ... What is it not displaying? It looks fine when I evaluate it on my machine. Can you post a pic of what you're seeing?

Comment: It cuts off at x=0, it used to be a full line all the way through. Pic posted.

Comment: What if you use `Exclusions -> None` in your `Plot` command?

Comment: No idea what are you asking about. You type `{x, -1, 5}` and `PlotRange -> {-10, 500}`, and the plot is displayed (fully) in those ranges.

Comment: Try adding the `Plot` option `Exclusions -> None`. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you user6014, that worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one of the past few releases (sometime around Mathematica 11.0?) there was a change to how `Exclusions` are calculated. I forget the specifics of the change, but if you prefer Mathematica not automatically exclude anything use `Exclusions -> None`:

```
V[x_] := Which[x < 0, 400, x > 4, 400, True, 0]
Plot[V[x], {x, -1, 5}, Axes -> False, FrameLabel -> {x, V}, 
 Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {-10, 500}, PlotPoints -> 150, 
 Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]